# Java Swing for Web Development by converting to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, swing

Good day!

With regards to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202525/making-web-forms-java-vs-html) about Java Swing being used for web development, I have a job interview today and they told me that their company uses Swing then convert it to javascript then deploy it on the web.

Can anyone explain this to me better? What books / websites should I study so that I could understand how this is done. Is this a good / common practice?

Thank you very much.

Comment: research GWT. It isn't Swing-based though, which is a good thing imo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at CreamTec's [AjaxSwing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/). I've played around with it several times and it's the only product I know so far that takes your existing Swing GUI and converts it into something displayable in your browser.

Whether this is good practice or not is not really easy to answer. This solution works well as long as your application does not need to scale largely. CreamTec states that their solution is suited for about 50 clients IIRC.
The markup generated by AjaxSwing can in no way be called semantic but that is a common thing with these kinds of generators.
You can try AjaxSwing pretty easily since it does not require you to do much configuration but my recommendation is to use a dedicated web framework if you want higher scalability.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like GWT also. Granted that is not what the person said, but if it was a recruiter, they may been confused on the exact technology.

Answer (score 2):

AjaxSwing is a run-time tool and needs a server license for commercial use.

You might want to try Mia Transformer www.mia-software.com. They change Swing Java code to GWT Java Code and GWT changes it to Javascript and then if you want you can use Google V8 compiler for faster execution. Of course it is not 100%. We are going to try it for a large project and see if it works.

The other link provided to us was http://swingweb.sourceforge.net/swingweb/. Have not checked it out though.

Will keep you posted. If you come across a workable solution please share.